# How to add relation between already existing items

Tags: node.js, model, loopbackjs

I have problem with writing a code for making a relation between tags and item.
(I can do it in Api Explorer by (PUT/items/{id}/tags/rel/{fk} -  but not in code)

I create a item with tags.
I do this by first creating item, 
then put all tags(unique on tags name) with `findOrCreate`.

But problem is with adding already existing tags to newly created item.

My Model is defined with:

```
  "relations": {
    "tags": {
      "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
      "model": "Tag",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
```

and code is:

```
  console.log(tagsArr);     //array of tags
  Item.findById(linkId,function (err,instance) {

    instance.tags.create(tagsArr, function (err, addedinstances) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  })
```

eighter i use `instance.tags.create()` or `instance.tags.add()` i get:

```
 ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it:

```
instance.__link__tags(tagId, function (err, added) {
               console.log(err);
               console.log(added);
             });
```

where `tags` is related model and `tagId` is a id number of existing tag.